# Is it possible to do by this using resourceful routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my models have accommodations that belong to a locality. With [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) my resourceful routes would look like this:

```
/localities
/localities/:locality-name
/accommodations
/accommodations/:accommodation-name
```

The problem is that I'd like to have the accommodation detail URL look like:

```
/accommodations/:locality-name/:accommodation-name
```

and also have a locality filter for accommodations:

```
/accommodations/:locality-name
```

Naturally I can add the following to `routes.rb`:

```
resources :localities do
  resources :accommodations
end
```

... which would result in:

```
/localities/:locality-name
/localities/:locality-name/accommodations
/localities/:locality-name/accommodations/:accommodation-name
```

But I would like the accommodations to begin with `/accommodations` and not get nested under localities.

The closest I got is by modifying the above to this:

```
resources :localities, :path => 'accommodations' do
  resources :accommodations, :path => '', :except => :index
end
```

This does what I want, but turns things upside down and sort of messes up both my resources. Additionally I could add `resources :localities, :path => 'localities'` to `routes.rb` but then the localities index view would appear for both `/localities` and `/accommodations`. And I would like these URLs to act as some sort of portals for the stuff they stand for.

So, should I give up on resourceful routes? Or is there a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: since you only have one route in mind, probably the simplest would be: `match 'accommodations/:locality-name/:accommodation-name' => 'accomodations#show'`

Comment: thanks, i guess i'll go down this route (pun intended) :)